# The acyclic carrier theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Mosher & Tangora's book *Cohomology Operations and Operations in Homotopy Theory*, they define an $h$-equivariant carrier as in the excerpt below. But I don't quite understand the definitions here. $\pi$ is a group,$K$ is a $\pi$-free chain complex with a $Z[\pi]$ basis $B$ of homogeneous elements. I wonder what does a $Z[\pi]$-basis means here for a chain complex.

> To state the fundamental theorem on acyclic carriers, we need some terminology.
> Let $\pi$ and $G$ be groups (not necessarily abelian) and let $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$
> denote the group ring of $\pi$. Let $K$ be a $\pi$-free chain complex with a
> $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$-basis $B$ of homogeneous elements, called "cells."
> For two cells $\sigma, \tau \in B$, let $[\tau : \sigma]$ denote the coefficient of
> $\sigma$ in $\partial \tau$; this is an element in $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$. Let $L$ be
> a chain complex on which $G$ acts, and let $h$ be a homomorphism $\pi \to G$.
>
> **Definition:**
> An *$h$-equivariant carrier* $\mathcal{C}$ from $K$ to $L$ is a function
> $\mathcal{C}$ from $B$ to the subcomplexes of $L$ such that:
>
> 1. if $[\tau : \sigma] \neq 0$ then $\mathcal{C} \sigma \subset \mathcal{C} \tau$
> 2. for $x \in \pi$ and $\sigma \in B$, $h(x) \mathcal{C} \sigma \subset \mathcal{C} \sigma$
>
> The carrier $\mathcal{C}$ is said to be *acyclic* if the subcomplex
> $\mathcal{C} \sigma$ is acyclic for every cell $\sigma \in B$.
> The $h$-chain map $f : K \to L$ is said to be *carried by* $\mathcal{C}$
> if $f \sigma \in \sigma \mathcal{C}$ for every $\sigma \in B$.

Comment: $Z[\pi]$ is a ring, and a $Z[\pi]$-basis means a basis for a free module structure over $Z[\pi]$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which is not). In the future you should do the same so that other users with similar questions will have an easier time finding this ^_^

Comment: The name is Mosh**er** ...

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks! How do I view a $Z[\pi]$-basis as a basis for the chain complex?

Comment: I also came across the same problem. It appears to me that, in Elements of Algebraic Topology (page 75), Munkres defines the basis of a chain complex $\{C_{i},\partial_{i}\}$ to consist of the basis of each of the free module $C_{i}$. Since you asked this question 6 months ago, could you please confirm this?